# How can I solve - Uncaught TypeError: removeIndividualBook is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent-child

I have `removeIndividualBook` in `index.js` which removes individual book. This functionality was working fine from `Book` component.

I am creating new component `Quantity` and trying to access `removeIndividualBook`  there. I am passing `removeIndividualBook`  as prop from index.js to Book.js to Quantity.js.

In Quantity.js I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: removeIndividualBook is not a function`

index.js

```
  // Remove Individual book
  const removeIndividualBook = (id) => {
    const updatedBookData = booksData.filter((book) => {
      return book.id !== id;
    });
    setBooksData(updatedBookData);
  };

<Book key={index} {...book} removeIndividualBook={removeIndividualBook}></Book>
```

Book.js

```
const Book = ({description,id,removeIndividualBook}) => {
  const clickHandler = () => {
    alert(description);
  };
      <Quantity id={id} removeIndividualBook={removeIndividualBook} />
```

Quantity.js

```
const Quantity = (id, removeIndividualBook) => {const Quantity = (id, removeIndividualBook) => {}


return (
    <>
      <button
        className="button" onClick={() => removeIndividualBook(id)}> ------>>> Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in your Quantity.js component, your syntax is not good. It should be

```
const Quantity = ({id, removeIndividualBook}) => {

return (
    <>
      <button
        className="button" onClick={() => removeIndividualBook(id)}>
...
)
```

the props should be wrapped in `{ }` (destructed). I think that is the problem you are providing.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced somehow your components with a code snippet.

I think your problem is because you are not destructuring props correctly, `(id, removeIndividualBook)`, they should be `({id, removeIndividualBook})`.

Here is the link that you can see that it works properly:

[Code Snippet Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mccarthy-zlcl4?file=/src/Book.js)

Hope this solves your issue!